# How to get a value from multiple functions in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

Let's suppose that the objective function is

```
max z(x,y) = f1(x) - f2(y)
```

where `f1` is function of variables `x` and `f2` is functions of variables `y`.

This could be written in Pyomo as

```
def z(model):
    return f1(model) - f2(model)

def f1(model):
    return [some summation of x variables with some coefficients]

def f2(model):
    return [some summation of y variables with some coefficients]

model.objective = Objective(rule=z)
```

I know it is possible to get the numeric value of `z(x,y)` easily by calling (since it is the objective function) :

```
print(model.objective())
```

but is there a way to get the numeric value of any of these sub-functions separetedly after the optimization, even if they are not explicitly defined as objectives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your question in terms of a ConcreteModel, since rules in Pyomo, for the most part, are nothing more than a mechanism to delay building a ConcereteModel. For now, they are also required to define indexed objects, but that will likely change soon.

First, there is nothing stopping you from defining those "rules" as standard functions that take in some argument and return a value. E.g.,

```
def z(x, y):
    return f1(x) - f2(y)
def f1(x):
    return x + 1
def f2(x):
    return y**2
```

Now if you call any of these functions with a built-in type (e.g., f(1,5)), you will get a number back. However, if you call them with Pyomo variables (or Pyomo expressions) you will get a Pyomo expression back, which you can assign to an objective or constraint. This works because Pyomo modeling components, such as variables, overload the standard algebraic operators like +, -, *, etc. Here is an example of how you can build an objective with these functions:

```
import pyomo.environ as aml
m = aml.ConcreteModel()
m.x = aml.Var()
m.y = aml.Var()
m.o = aml.Objective(expr= z(m.x, m.y))
```

Now if m.x and m.y have a value loaded into them (i.e., the .value attribute is something other than `None`), then you can call one of the sub-functions with them and evaluate the returned expression (slower)

```
aml.value(f1(m.x))
aml.value(f2(m.y))
```

or you can extract the value from them and pass that to the sub-functions (faster)

```
f1(m.x.value)
f2(m.y.value)
```

You can also use the [Expression](https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_code_expression_code_objects) object to store sub-expressions that you want to evaluate on the fly or share inside multiple other expression on a model (all of which you can update by changing what expression is stored under the Expression object).